# A property of twin primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, twin-primes

$(a,b)$ is a couple of twin primes such that $b=a+2$ and $a > 29$.
Let $N = 4^b$ and $q$ the quotient which results from the division of $N$ by $a$ and $r$ is the remainder.
We calculate $P = (q\bmod b)a+r-1$
Below we prove that $P = 3(10b+1)$ using Fermat's little theorem.

$N=16\cdot4^a\equiv64\pmod a$ then $r=64$ ($a > 64$)
$4^b=(b-2)q+64$ then $4\equiv64-2q\pmod b$ and $q\equiv30\pmod b$
Finally we have $P=30a+63=3(10b+1)$

My question is :

1. Is the proof correct?
2. I was wondering if there is another way to proof this property?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics. Use `\times` ($\times$), `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or simple use juxtaposition.

Comment: @CrawCraw Welcome to Math SE. One small thing is that your first line has the restriction $a \gt 29$, but then in the next paragraph you require that $a \gt 64$. Otherwise, offhand, I don't see anything incorrect with your proof.

Comment: There's always another way to prove a property, but your way is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'm unclear about your third line; is that supposed to be the binary mod operation, or did you mean $P = qa+r-1 \pmod b$? Also interested in @JohnOmielan 's question about $29$ and $64$.